How to detect seasonality(multiplicative or additive) in a time series data?
I usually figure out if it's additive by looking at a time plot or using an STL decomposition—it’s pretty clear that way. But my friends insists on using the RMSE of Holt-Winters’ additive and multiplicative methods on a test set to decide. They argue that since the RMSE of the multiplicative model is smaller, it must be multiplicative.



I suggest you post this question in cross validated since it has a clear statistics focus
